# Getting form values without input

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<form method="POST" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"><button type='submit'>Yes</button></form>";
echo "<form method="POST" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '"><button type='submit'>No</button></form>";
```

I want to make 2 buttons, but not sure how to make them send $_POST["yes"] and $_POST["no"].

Comment: why two forms with one buttons? You could just use one form with two submit buttons having different value attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way would be to use a single form with two submit buttons:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="answer" value="Yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="answer" value="No" />
</form>
```

To see it in action, add:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to your PHP. You should see that only the button you clicked on is sent.

Comment: Didn't knew you could add 2 submit buttons to a form.

Comment: Still, how do I get access to the answer? Like $_POST["value"]